# Json to xml conversion generating confusing xml string

Tags: java, json, xml, gson

I have a DTO class which I was converting it to json and storing to DB. Now I need the corresponding XML file for Json.

```
Class FooDto {
    private String id;
    // Array of strings.
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    // Object of some other class having two values String socId and String socName.
    private SomeOtherClass soc;
}
```

I am using *gson* google library for create json object and xml string.

```
FooDto fooDto = new FooDto();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toString(fooDto);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String xmlString = XML.toString(json, "Parent");
```

When each member of FooDto object contains some value it generates a perfect xml.

```
<Parent>
  <id>Some id</id>
  <names>John</names>
  <names>Mac</names>
  <soc>
    <socId>123</socId>
    <socName>XYZ</socName>
  </soc>
</Parent>
```

But the problem is when the value in the object is empty it generates a confusing xml which is not possible to convert the same json and the class object afterwards.

**For Empty Object to JSON String is**

> {id:"",
>   names:[""],
>   soc:{}}

**For JSON to XML String is**

```
<Parent>
  </id>
  </names>
  <soc></soc>
</Parent>
```

**Regenerating JSON from XML**

> {id:{},
>   names:{},
>   soc:{}}

And its causing an error when I am creating class object from this json as its expecting id as string and names as array of string. Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need JSON at all? If you're just dealing with XML, then stick to XStream, for example

Comment: No, I need Json as well to store it in the DB.

Comment: Are not allowed to store XML into the database?